# Nesting a multiple model serializer in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

A week old Django baby needs some help! I have the following model structure.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="+")

class Route(models.Model):        
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
    notifier = models.ForeignKey(Notifier)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Notifier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

class Match(models.Model):        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    metric_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(
        Notification, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

I want to GET a list in the following format and want my API to be able to filter on entity_name, metric_name, status_user

```
{
"routes": {
    "email":["abc@gmail.com"],
    "slack":["name_of_slack_channel"],
},
"name": "sample",
"metric":"CPU",
"entity":"some_enttity",
"status":0,
"user":"ent@gmail.com"
}
```

Notifications is a mapping of the route model fields `notifier: destination`.
Every row in route will be something of the sort `<notificationID, email, "abc@gmail.com>`  or `<notificationID, slack, "slackchannel>`

I am able to get what I need using the `routes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` field and using `select_related('notifier')`

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    routes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = (
            'name', 'routes'
        )

    def get_routes(self, obj):
        related_routes = 
             Route.objects.filter(notification_id=obj.pk).
                  select_related('notifier')
        all_routes = {}
        for route in related_routes:
            if route.notifier.name in all_routes:
                all_routes[route.notifier.name] += [route.destination]
            else:
                all_routes[route.notifier.name] = [route.destination]
        return all_routes
```

But I am sure there can be a better way to do this, without doing all this processing and having to fetch Route objects in get_routes. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!